# How can I get the shopping cart in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to share a user's cart via ajax request. How do I do this?

In the code below, the cart information is returning empty

```
    public function __construct(){
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'renderAdmin']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_ajax'       , [$this, 'myAjax'] );
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax', [$this, 'myAjax'] );
    }

    public function myAjax(){
        defined( 'WC_ABSPATH' ) || exit;
        $response = [];

        // Load cart functions which are loaded only on the front-end.
        include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php';
        include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/class-wc-cart.php';

        if (WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
            wc_load_cart();
        }

        $response['response'] = WC()->cart;

        wp_send_json($response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line if **(WC()->cart->is_empty())** is unnecessary because the cart should be loaded already if you included the cart functions and class. So, you don't need to check if the cart is empty before proceeding.

Updated of your code:

```
public function __construct() {

add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'renderAdmin']);
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax', [$this, 'myAjax']);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax', [$this, 'myAjax']);
} 

public function myAjax() {
defined('WC_ABSPATH') || exit;        

// Ensure the user is logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_send_json_error('User not logged in.');

}

// Check if WooCommerce is active and initialized

if (!function_exists('WC')) {
    wp_send_json_error('WooCommerce is not active.');
}    

// Load cart functions which are loaded only on the front-end.
include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php';
include_once WC_ABSPATH .
 'includes/class-wc-cart.php';    

// Load the current user's cart
wc_load_cart();  

$response['response'] = WC()->cart;

wp_send_json($response);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. So, can I get this information with the customer number without logging in?